# Shopware 5 : How to get Article url using REST Api?

Tags: shopware

I have used below api

```
http://my-shop/api/articles/3
```

it works peferct but i want to use url of that product

However in response product url is missing.

So how can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

The API has no knowledge of the storefront routing. If you need the url, you will have to implement this via plugin.

Comment: I have checked for Extend a REST API resource.But i have no idea to how to get product url ,can you please guide with code to implement product url?

Comment: I can't provide you any ready-to-use solution. You need to extend the rest-api.

Extending rest api via plugin: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/extend-api-resource/#search-results

Comment: But how can to i get ( build ) product url from productid??Please help me with some code

Comment: There are a lot of examples directly in the source code, here is an example from the backend: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/1f06556984f5f3ac5a41f428428461165b761407/engine/Shopware/Controllers/Backend/Article.php#L2231

You can use the container to get the router and assemble your url.

Comment: I have used plugin from this link https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/extend-api-resource/#search-results but not get how to use container and route as i am new to shopware 5

Comment: I have created a controller and i can managed to get product url in it.Now but i dont know how i can use this controller in Extende api controller.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following URL for an article with given `articleID`:

```
https://yourshop.com/index.php?sViewport=detail&sArticle={articleID}
```

Note that, as Rotfuchs mentioned, to get the "real" URL as presented in the frontend (with SEO stuff), you would need to write a plugin to extend the `/api/articles/` endpoint.